# In a normal GLM is the dispersion parameter equal to the marginal variance?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, variance

I am trying to compare variances across models, am i correct in thinking that in a normal GLM the variance is equal to the dispersion parameter. So is my dispersion parameter is 40.1 my variance is the same value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in a normal generalized linear model (GLM) the dispersion parameter and the variance are the same thing.

If you are fitting a normal GLM with identity link (which is the default) then you may as well use `lm()` instead of `glm()` because it does exactly the same fit but with output in the familiar linear model form.